# Apply an already defined function to all dataframes at once

Tags: r, lapply

I already have defined a function (which works fine). Nevertheless, I have 20 dataframes in the working space to which I want to `lapply` the same function (dat1 to dat20).

So far it looks like this:

```
dat1 <- func(dat=dat1)
dat2 <- func(dat=dat2)
dat3 <- func(dat=dat3) 
dat4 <- func(dat=dat4)
...
dat20 <- func(dat=dat20)
```

However, is there a way to do this more elegant with a shorter command, i.e. to `lapply` the function to all dataframes at once?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
mylist <- paste0("dat", 1:20, sep="")
lapply(mylist, func)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
lapply(mget(ls(pattern="dat")),func)
```

Some details: The `pattern` argument in `ls` will limit which object names it lists (e.g., I assume you have other objects including your function in the global environment). `mget` retrieves those objects from the environment and turns them into a list, which you can then `lapply` your function over.

Comment: The results need to be assigned back to the workspace though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the name of a variable, you can use `get()` to retrieve the value from the workspace.  The corresponding assignment function is called `assign()`:

```
mylist <- paste0("dat", 1:20)
lapply(mylist, function(name) assign(name, func(dat=get(name))) )
```

Comment: Or somewhat shorter & more cryptic: `lapply(mylist, assign, func(dat=get(name)) )`

Answer (score 1):

The desired behavior can be obtained using eval instead of lapply.

Assume `mylist` to be the names of the data.frame you want to apply `fun` to. `mylist` might be generated using

```
mylist <- ls(pattern="dat")
```

Then you can use the following code to do exactly what you want:

```
cCmd  <- paste(mylist , "<- func(" ,mylist,")", sep="")
eCmd  <- parse(text=cCmd)
eval(eCmd)
```