# Apply function to a list of Data Frames and write the result back

Tags: r, lapply

I have the names of a group of data frames given in the variable "dfs", as an array of Strings. I.e.

```
> dfs
"dfs1" "dfs2" ... "dfsk"
```

I want to rename the columns of each of the data frame in dfs. That means I want to apply a function 'func' to each of the entries in dfs and write the result back. I.e. the result should be equal to evaluating

```
dfs1 <- func(dfs1)
dfs2 <- func(dfs2)
...
dfsk <- func(dfsk)
```

The difficulty is, that dfs might be arbitrarily long and the content of dfs is only known at runtime.

I have tried to write a function func and apply it to dfs using:

```
lapply( mget(dfs), func)
```

However this leaves the actual data.frames unchanged.

My Question has similarities to the following unanswered Question:

[Apply an already defined function to all dataframes at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389767/apply-an-already-defined-function-to-all-dataframes-at-once)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: @David `func` changes colnames of each data.frame

Comment: Can you post some sample data sets and the `func` syntax into the question?

Comment: @Philip: Which Point in http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx should are you refering to?

Comment: In your example, just add `assign(dfs[1], mtcars)`

Comment: With your `apply` call the columns don't change, but you have a _single_ object that holds the changed data.frames. You can work on each element using `lapply`. Now isn't that neat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In found a Solution: The key is to use eval instead of apply. The desired behavior can be obtained using:

```
cCmd  <- paste(dfs, "<- func(" ,dfs,")", sep="")
eCmd  <- parse(text=cCmd)
eval(eCmd)
```

This might not be the most elegant way, but it works.